# how to pushback on a vector of vectors?

Tags: c++, vector

I am taking 20 lines of input. I want to separate the contents of each line by a space and put it into a vector of vectors. How do I make a vector of vectors? I am having have struggles pushing it back...

My input file:

```
Mary had a little lamb
lalala up the hill
the sun is up
```

The vector should look like something like this.

```
ROW 0: {"Mary","had", "a","little","lamb"}
ROW 1: {"lalala","up","the","hill"}
```

This is my code....

```
string line; 
vector <vector<string> > big;
string buf;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    getline(cin, line);
    stringstream ss(line);

    while (ss >> buf){
        (big[i]).push_back(buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a vector of vectors over there. What's wrong with your code?

Comment: @AndyProwl out of bounds access (assuming the code is a good representation of the real one).

Comment: @juanchopanza: Oh, right :) Good catch

Comment: +vote for mary had a little lamb instead of foo/bar

Answer (score 14):

The code is right, but your vector has zero elements in it so you cannot access `big[i]`.

Set the vector size before the loop, either in the constructor or like this:

```
big.resize(ruleNum);
```

Alternatively you can push an empty vector in each loop step:

```
big.push_back( vector<string>() );
```

You don't need the parentheses around `big[i]` either.

Answer (score 5):

Yo could start with a vector of size `ruleNum`

```
vector <vector<string> > big(ruleNum);
```

This will hold `ruleNum` empty `vector<string>` elements. You can then push back elements into each one, as you are currently doing in the example you posted.

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:

```
string line; 
vector <vector<string> > big;  //BTW:In C++11, you can skip the space between > and >

string currStr;
for (int i = 0; i < ruleNum; i++){
    getline(cin, line);
    stringstream ss(line);
    vector<string> buf;
    while (ss >> currStr){
       buf.push_back(buf);
    }
    big.push_back(buf);
}
```

Comment: No need declaring `buf` outside the outer loop, and in fact you forget to clear it inside the loop because of that.

Comment: @KonradRudolph You are right, I was careless, code just updated. Thanks!

Comment: Haha, now you’re doing unnecessary work, the vector is redefined every time and therefore empty, no need to `clear()` it.

Comment: @KonradRudolph updated again, but put clear() there does not hurt correctness. It is redundant I agree. thanks!

Comment: Would it make sense to move buf into big? Or is it the case that copy elision takes place, so there is no reason for it?

Answer (score 3):

```
              vector<vector<string> > v;
```

to push_back into vectors of vectors, we will push_back strings in the internal vector and push_back the internal vector in to the external vector.

Simple code to show its implementation:

```
vector<vector<string> > v;
vector<string> s;

s.push_back("Stack");
s.push_back("oveflow");`
s.push_back("c++");
// now push_back the entire vector "s" into "v"
v.push_back(s);
```